# Leaflet layers somehow interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, animation, leaflet

I have a javascript function that creates a leaflet layer group, adds it to a map, removes it and then repeats. Each time, it goes through a json array that has the data which is placed in the layer group. The effect is an animation of data points on the map.

There are two data sets which are formatted to be animated with this function. Let's call them Nowcast and Forecast. In my app, if I run the animations in the following sequence:

Nowcast, Forecast, Nowcast, Forecast, Nowcast

On the third Nowcast run, it looks like some of the data from the Forecast shows up along with the Nowcast data. Not all the data, and only for a few iterations, but then it just sits there and does not disappear when the animation is over. The only way to get this weird residual data is to run the Forecast animation again. (running the Nowcast again does not remove it).

Anyway, here is the function:

```
function animateAshData(inputData,dataLayer) {
    var currentTime = inputData.ashData[t];
    var currentAshData = currentTime.concentrations;
    window.Android.toLogCat("t = " + currentTime.date + " " + t);
    window.Android.toLogCat("Current set size= " + currentAshData.length);
    if (dataLayer != undefined) { //The map has a data layer already been created from previous time step, so remove it
        removeDataLayer(dataLayer);
    }

    var currentAshLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
    for (j = 0; j<currentAshData.length; j++) {
        L.marker([currentAshData[j].lat, currentAshData[j].lon],{icon: ashIcon}).addTo(currentAshLayerGroup);
        map.addLayer(currentAshLayerGroup);
        };
    t = t+1;
    // Queue up the animation to the next time step
    tid = setTimeout(function(){
      if (t > finalt) {
        //end of animation
        window.Android.toLogCat("Done with animation");
        removeDataLayer(currentAshLayerGroup);
        window.clearTimeout(tid);
      } else {
     //     delete currentTime.concentrations; 
        clearMap();
        animateAshData(inputData,currentAshLayerGroup);
        }
    }, 100);
```

My first thought was that the layer groups were somehow persisting, even though I had a map.removeLayer(layer) in there (although it is mysterious why it takes 3 iterations instead of just 2 for this to show up...). So, I made a removeDataLayer() function and added a layer.clearLayers(). This did not work either. I finally added the function from here [Clear all polylines from leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585688/clear-all-polylines-from-leaflet-map) to just try clearing everything, but this still did not work. Here is my removeDataLayer function:

```
function removeDataLayer(layer){
    map.removeLayer(layer);
    layer.clearLayers();
    clearMap();
};

 function clearMap(){
    for(i in map._layers){
        if(map._layers[i]._path != undefined)
        {
             try{
                map.removeLayer(map._layers[i]);
            }
        catch(e){
                console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Anyway, I can't imagine I am the only one with problems with leaflet layers interfering with each other and/or problems removing them completely. Thanks in advance.