# Delete all polyline from map before creating new polyline

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I am using leaflet to show the map and create the polyline.
I want to delete all the polyline before creating any new polyline.

When I am creating polyline ,

I stored all polyline in **array - $scope.polycoords = [] ;**

To remove all  polyline I am using this code.

```
for(var i = 0; i< $scope.polycoords.length; i++){
   map.removeLayer($scope.polycoords[i]);
}
```

But its not working.
Giving me this error - **Error: map.removeLayer is not a function**
How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593494/8375199) answer?

Comment: Yes I checked that. That did not work for me. I did by this way                           I created a function after the polyline create and I can call this function where I want to remove all polyline.
  $scope.removePolyLine = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i< $scope.polycoords.length; i++){
    var polyline = $scope.polycoords[i];
         map.removeLayer(polyline);
     } 
 }

Comment: Check to make sure your map variable hasn't been overriden. If map is a leaflet map, it removeLayer should be a function

Answer (score 2):

May it's to late for you but this works for me:

Use **L.featureGroup()**:

```
var active_polyline = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
```

When you create the first polylines, add each of them to the active_polyline thru a loop

```
polyline = L.polyline(mypolyline).addTo(active_polyline);
```

Empty the L.featureGroup() before creating a new polyline in order to delete the previous ones:

```
active_polyline.clearLayers();
```

Then create the new one:

```
polyline = L.polyline(mynewpolyline).addTo(active_polyline);
```